# How to write a stabby lambda wrapper scope, that is a composition of other scope names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid, chaining, querying

A simple example for illustration, this is not actually what I'm trying to do:

I have two scopes on a user model:

```
scope :unarchived, -> { where archived: false }
scope :active, -> { where active: true }
```

For convenience and dryness, I want a scope called :awake that is the combination of User.unarchived.active written in the stabby lambda notation. 
**NOTE, I know I can write something like this:**

```
def self.awake
  self.unarchived.active
end
```

I would like to know if and how this is possible inside a lambda scope definition and if not, I would appreciate an explanation or a link as to why it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I just realised, it is straight forward. I just needed to notice, that inside the lambda is an expression, that returns a query/criteria object. simply writing:

```
scope :awake, -> { self.unarchived.active }
```

or even simpler as mentioned below:

```
scope :awake, -> { unarchived.active }
```

does the trick.